# How to change Recycler Item Color?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

[image: OUTPUT...]

I have `RecyclerView` and I am inflating data. My requirement is that I have to show first item text in black color, the rest of the items should be in grey. And when user scroll then that grey color item should be black and its follower would be in grey again. I was thinking to this using position but I am confused.

```
    public class RecyclerViewAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerViewAdapter.ViewHolder>
    implements RecyclerViewFastScroller.BubbleTextGetter {

    private List<String> mDataArray;

    public RecyclerViewAdapter(List<String> dataset) {
        mDataArray = dataset;
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        if (mDataArray == null)
            return 0;
        return mDataArray.size();
    }

    @Override
    public RecyclerViewAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item_recycler_view_layout, parent, false);
        ViewHolder vh = new ViewHolder(v);
        return vh;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        holder.mTextView.setText(mDataArray.get(position));

    }

    @Override
    public String getTextToShowInBubble(int pos) {
        if (pos < 0 || pos >= mDataArray.size())
            return null;

        String name = mDataArray.get(pos);
        if (name == null || name.length() < 1)
            return null;
        return mDataArray.get(pos).substring(0, 1);

    }

    public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        @Bind(R.id.tv_alphabet)
        public TextView mTextView;

        public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            ButterKnife.bind(this, itemView);
        }
    }

}
```

**My updated code for onScrollIng and dynamic changing**

```
  @Override
public void onBindViewHolder(MessageAdapter.ViewHolder holder, int position) {

    /*Tuesday, April 10, 2001 3:51 PM*/

    msgModels = msgList.get(position);
    if (msgList.get(position) != null) {

            holder.msgTitle.setText(msgModels.getMessageTitle());
            holder.msgDescription.setText(msgModels.getMessageDescription());
            holder.msgDate.setText(msgModels.getMessageDate());
    }

    if (position == firstVisible) {
        holder.msgTitle.setTextColor(Color.RED);
        holder.msgDescription.setTextColor(Color.RED);
        holder.msgDate.setTextColor(Color.RED);
    }else{
        holder.msgTitle.setTextColor(Color.BLUE);
        holder.msgDescription.setTextColor(Color.BLUE);
        holder.msgDate.setTextColor(Color.BLUE);
    }


}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return msgList.size();
}

private int firstVisible = 0;

public void changeItem(int position){
    firstVisible = position;
    notifyItemChanged(firstVisible);
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}


public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    public TextView msgTitle, msgDescription,msgDate;

    public ViewHolder(View view) {
        super(view);
        msgTitle  = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.msgTitle);
        msgDescription  = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.msgDescription);
        msgDate  = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.msgDate);
    }
}
}
```

**My Activity where I am calling Recycler onScroll**

```
 private ProgressDialog mProgressDialog = null;
private static final String API_MSG_CALL = "API_MSG_CALL";
private Map<String, String> mapobject;
private LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_message, null);
    mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.recycler_viewLaws);
    mRecyclerView.setAdapter(msgAdapter);
    mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));
    msgAdapter = new MessageAdapter(msgList, getActivity(), this);

    linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());

    //msgAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    mProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());

    mRecyclerView.addOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
        @Override
        public void onScrolled(RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {
            super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy);
            int firstVisible = linearLayoutManager.findFirstCompletelyVisibleItemPosition();
            msgAdapter.changeItem(firstVisible);
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 4):

use `holder.itemView.setBackgroundColor(...);`

Example

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    holder.itemView.setBackgroundColor(yourcolor);
    holder.mTextView.setText(mDataArray.get(position));

}
```

Update:

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    if(position==0){
        holder.itemView.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);
    }else{
        holder.itemView.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREY);

    }
    holder.mTextView.setText(mDataArray.get(position));

}
```

Comment: Thnxx for your reply but I have to put only first Item in Black. rest would be  in Gray

Comment: Updated my answer please check

Comment: Thank you but One more help I need sir.. For 0 position My data is change and other is in different color. Now I scrolled page then 0 position gone invisible. and lets asume 10th position is now on top. so how can I again make 10th position Black and rest visible part in Grey ?

Comment: @Target , you can use visible item count for getting top most position in each scrolling condition and then set color something like above code.

Answer (score 4):

first in your main Activity use this code to find the first visible item:

```
        recyclerview.addOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
        @Override
        public void onScrolled(RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {
            super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy);
            int firstVisible = linearLayoutManager.findFirstCompletelyVisibleItemPosition();
            RecyclerViewAdapter.changeItem(firstVisible);
        }
    });
```

then in your Adapter add this method:

```
    private int firstVisible = 0;

    public void changeItem(int position){
    firstVisible = position;
    notifyItemChanged(firstVisible);
    notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
```

and in onBindViewHolder add this code:

```
   if (position == firstVisible) {
        holder.txtNumber.setBackgroundColor(mContext.getResources().getColor(R.color.black));
    }
```

I just use a text as an example but you can change the cardview's background too

Comment: Thnxx sir but for  1 milliseconds its changing color and then Entire RecyclerView data is black..:(

Comment: Yes on minute sir

Comment: Yes Sir, Please find Tag my Updated code  Heading in my code.. I put both MainActiovity and Adapter Value.. Please give your valuable suggestion. I want to make first Recycler Item either it comes from 0 index or after scrolling it comes 9 position. First top Item should be in Black and rest should be in Red. PLease help me

Comment: I have strong believe that you can surely help me. I am stuck on this for last 2 days..

Comment: try removing the else part and put the default color in xml code, maybe it will solve it

Comment: Sir, I am sorry.. No luck... :(

Comment: can show me the recyclerview's picture after changing color

Comment: Okay Sir. Wait for a while. I am uploading

Comment: @Mousad Vali sir, Please check my output in genymotion. . Index  must be red and when I am scrolling then  data is arranging according to data size but again its indexes not heilighted.

Comment: @Mousad Vali sir, Are you there ?

Comment: i don't know anything more right now, i have to think about it

Comment: did you try it on real device, because it's working on my phone

Comment: @Mousad Vali.. Thank you sir so much. I resolved it.. Actually problem was in My LinearLayoutManager which was Golbally Declared and  findFirstVisibleItemPosition ws returning always -1 so I solved it.. thank you so much for you support and help.. U r awesome. :)

Comment: you're welcome. so please set this as right answer to inform other people